# Make a multiprocess UDP server with Python, one process for listening to one port

Tags: python, udp, multiprocessing

I want make a multiprocess UDP server with Python, listen one port for each process from a class:

`processListener.py`:

```
import multiprocessing
import socket

class processListener(multiprocessing.Process):
def __init__(self):
    multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
    self.data = None

def run(self):
    self.startServer()
    return

def startServer(self):
    udpSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    address = ('', self.port)
    udpSocket.bind(address)
    while 1:
        data, client = udpSocket.recvfrom(1024)
        print self.data, '>>>', data.strip()
        self.data = data.strip()
        udpSocket.sendto('ACK', client)
    return
```

and my main file is `server.py`:

```
from processListener import *

# Variable Definition
port = 4000

# Sever Initialization
if __name__ == '__main__':

process = processListener()
process.port = port
process.start()

while True:
    command = raw_input()
    if command == 'showdata':
            print 'Last Data is:', process.data
```

When the server is running and I send data to localhost:4000 from UDP

```
shell$ 
None >>> Test Data
```

But the problem starts when I use the command `showdata`

```
shell$
None >>> Test Data
showdata
Last Data is: None
```

Comment: As a side note, don't use getters and setters like you do in Python. Use direct property access (e.g. prefer `a.data` over `a.getData()`). If you need, you can use `@property` decorator (and its derivatives) to implement accessors and modifiers.

Comment: I have tried using `print process.data` but I have the same result, thanks

Comment: Yes, I know that it's not the solution. It is a Python programming tip ;)

Comment: Ohhh! Thanks for the tip, now I get it and yes I have experience with other programming languages  but I'm new with python.

Comment: why do you use a separate process here?

Comment: For use multiple process with multiple ports to listening, but now I'm working only with one

Comment: why do you need a process instead of a thread or even a select loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple processes do not share state by default.

You are accessing `processListener` instance from `server.py` process. `processListener.py` process has its own `processListener` instance (that has non-`None` data attribute).

To demonstrate it, replace `multiprocessing.Process` by `threading.Thread`. Multiple threads share objects by default and you should see non-`None` data.

Comment: Ok I understand that, but you maybe you Know some way to do the same thing but working?

Comment: read the docs on [how to share state between processes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes)